# Regular Expression for atmost and atleast one alpha and 14 numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expression should work for following

> a12345678910123 **Right**
>
> 123456789a12345 **Right**
>
> 12345678gh12345 **Wrong**
>
> 1235453de   **Wrong**

Comment: Does it *have* to be a regular expression? This can be done pretty easily without.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and we'll help refine it. This isn't a "write your code for you" site.

Comment: Any one know how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done like this -

`/^(?=\d*[a-z]\d*$)(?=(?:[a-z]*\d){14})[a-z\d]+$/I`

Formatted:

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?= \d* [a-z] \d* $ )         # Only 1 alpha
 (?=
      (?: [a-z]* \d ){14}           # at least 14 numeric
 )
 [a-z\d]+                      # Alpha-nums
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: Brilliant...Thankyou.....

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote and/or accept if usefull.

Comment: My reputation is not 15 yet that why i am not able to upvote